# Interactive filter for highcharter plots on flexdashboard WITHOUT shiny

Tags: html, r, filter, flexdashboard, r-highcharter

I need a solution to create a flexdashboard (in R) with live filtering (i.e. my coworker can select "Hospital A" from a dropdown menu and the dashboard will populate with Hospital A's data, etc.) WITHOUT using Shiny (final format will be HTML rendered from an RMarkdown file).

All of my visualizations are built with highcharter; I could build them with ggplot2 and add tooltip functionality with plotly in order to use crosstalk, but I would strongly prefer to continue using highcharter. I see that highcharter version 0.7.0 had a [crosstalk widget](https://stackoverflow.com) but the current version does not.

Any potential solutions to integrate live filtering into a flexdashboard within an RMarkdown file for dynamic HTML output would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

I have already built this functionality in Shiny but while my organization is exploring long-term solutions for dashboard-hosting servers, this information needs to be presented as an html document.